# It is possible when inputStream.available != 0 the complete data has not been received?

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth

I am using a BluetoothSocket in Android (in spp mode). I send data like this:

```
Packet sent﹕ 0xAA 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x01 0x14 0x00 0x00 0xB6 0x34
```

and i get response:

```
Packet received﹕ 0xAA 0x01 0x00 0x01 0x81 0x14 0x00 0x00 0x8F 0x34
```

But when I try to get a large response, I get the following error:

```
09-25 11:13:26.583    6442-6495E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1258
    Process: es.xxx.xxxx, PID: 6442
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=178; index=178
```

The error is in:

```
public void receive(int command, byte[] data) {

        if (data.length != 0) {
            int device = data[1];
            int par = data[5];
            short sizeData = (short)(((data[6]&0xFF) << 8) | ((data[7]&0xFF)));
            byte[] datos = new byte[sizeData];
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeData; i++) {
                datos[i] = data[8 + i]; // Here ocurred the error
            }
            switch (command) {
                case RETURN_PING:
                    break;
                case RETURN_MOUNT:
                ...
}
```

My method in order to read input data from bluetooth is (I made manual timeout following a response in StackOverflow):

```
 public byte[] read(){
        try {
            int timeout = 0;
            int maxTimeout = 10; // leads to a timeout of 2 seconds
            int available = 0;
            while((available = in.available()) == 0 && timeout < maxTimeout){
                timeout++;
                Thread.sleep(50);
            }
            receive = new byte[available];
            in.read(receive);
            return receive.clone();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (socket != null){
                close();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
}
```

So, my question is: It is possible when in.available != 0 the complete data has not been received yet? (in this way, method `receive` read bytes 6 and 7, where is store the packet lenght, but when this method try to iterate over all items it throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The major problem of your "read" is incorrect computing of how many bytes need to be read to get the whole package. There is a few main solutions how to pass and, then, read a data packet:

a. each packet has a header with its length specified

b. each packet has a predefined delimiter at its end, a kind of magic like "0x00" (this means you cannot use this byte in your data)

c. some other exotic ones

As I see, you use a. Then you may use something like this:

```
/**
 * equals to java.io.DatainputStream.readFully
 */
public static void readFully(InputStream in, byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
    if (len < 0) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    int n = 0;
    while (n < len) {
        final int count = in.read(b, off + n, len - n);
        if (count < 0) {
            throw new EOFException();
        }
        n += count;
    }
}    

public static int readByte (byte [] bytes, int offset) {
    return ((int) bytes [offset]) & 0xFF;
}

public static short readShort(byte [] bytes, int offset) {
    return (short)
        (readByte(bytes, offset) << 8 |
         readByte(bytes, offset + 1));
}
```

I see your header consists of 8 bytes. Then I'd suggest to do the following:

```
byte[] header = new byte[8];
readFully(in, header, 0, header.length);

int device = readByte(header, 1);
int par = readByte(header, 5);
int sizeData = readShort(header, 6);

byte[] data = new byte[sizeData];
readFully(in, data, 0, sizeData);
// now we have the whole data
```

2. After years of development I still have no a good idea what would we do with InputStream.available() :) To close a connection by data transmission timeout you could use 
   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)

or if not available, as in your case, a kind of timer

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

(update last receiving time after each call of readFully method and check the difference between current time and last receiving time by the timer)

Comment: Your example work like a charm! I have accepted your answer because you have provided a good example. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, can you explain your timer idea over example that you have provided? I don't understand fully because in.read() blocks execution so I don't know how I can use timer in order to do a timeout. thanks

Comment: Absolutely. in.read() blocks the current thread. That's why you need another one (a thread of Timer for instance http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) to check periodically how much time the reading thread has spent at in.read(). Save the current time in a volatile variable before in.read() is called, and check the difference between current time and saved value in TimerTask.run. If the timeout is reached, call Socket.close() to drop the connection and cancel your TimerTask.

Comment: But Socket.close() will close socket and maybe I want to continue use that socket. For example, in order to send NACK for send data again.

Comment: Yes, it closes the socket and in.read() returns the control back immediately with an exception and you can finish the reading thread. That's how the socket reading timeout works when you setSoTimeout() :) If you are going to use the socket all the time your application works, then may be you don't need a timeout at all :)

Comment: Oh... I think I understand you. You were waiting for incoming data was delivered to your side, just to get it when ready (when .available() shows some bytes can be read). If you use the code I posted, you don't need any timeouts at all.

Comment: Imagine the following: I read the first 8 bytes, I get the playlod size from bytes 6 and 7, imagine that size is 200 bytes, so I use readFully(in, data, 0, 200); and for some reason (maybe network/bluetooth problems) only receive 199 bytes, the readFully will listen for ever. I want to readFully only listen X seconds and if in that time doesn't receive data cancel read, but not close socket.

Comment: Moreover, generally speaking you may stop on reading of any byte including a header's one, including the second byte of your data size... And no one can say when the problem is resolved and the current instance of socket will works after that (but you can check). So, I'd suggest to close the socket in a timeout period if packet is still not read completely and prepare a new one and try to get data again. Just set it to a reasonable value (10s sec or so)

Answer (score 1):

> It is possible when inputStream.available != 0 the complete data has not been received?

There is nothing in its Javadoc that says anything about 'complete data'. The Javadoc correctly states that it is a measure of how much data may be read *without blocking.*

It *isn't:*

- a measure of the total length of the input stream
- an indicator of message boundaries
- an indicator of end of stream.

The Javadoc contains a specific warning about using its value to allocate a buffer ...

If you want a read timeout, use `Socket.setSoTimeout().`

Comment: BluetoothSocket in Android hasn't got setSoTimeout() method.